# R how to use files in the same packages

Tags: r, rstudio

I am planing to do all my R scripts in the same package in order to move it easily between my friends.

What I have done is created an R packages using R studio and the following files have been automatically generated:

```
projectName.Rproj
DESCRIPTION
man
NAMESPACE
R
Read-and-delete-me
```

I created a new R script and I save it in `R` folder. Now I want to add a new R script that uses functions that have been defined in the first script.

I created this new script and I tried to use on of the functions that are located in the other script. I got error that the function is not defined.

#### What I tried to solve the problem

I used the `source` command in the beginning of the new script like this:
`source('something.R')`
I got error message that `something.R` doesn't exist.

What is the solution please to include functions that exist in a different scripts ** but in the same packages**?

#### Note

I don't want to use relative paths because I want the package to be as portable as possible

Thanks a lot

Comment: @RichardScriven sorry but what does that do with my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to misunderstand how package works:  by having a file with a function in the `R/` directory, it *is already visible to other code in the package*.

If you want to make it available to other packages, you can control this via the `NAMESPACE` file.  All this is well-documented in [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) which comes with your copy of R, and a number of additional books and tutorials you could peruse.

Comment: but in my case i can't see that, i wrote a function in a R script inside a packages, but i couldn't use that function in another script in the same packages

Comment: Download a package from CRAN: pick _any_ package you are familiar with, but preferably a smaller one.  Study how it is structured.  Read the documentation.   You *still* have the wrong mental model, or maybe you never built or loaded the package...

Comment: No that is not correct, excuse me. You said `by having a file with a function in the R/ directory, it is already visible to other code in the package` and I replied by saying that my function is not visible to other script in the same packages. In other words, I am telling you that your answer isn't applying to my case. but i don't know why, can you help please?

Comment: Please stop repeating the same thing over and over; rather look at a package. See eg [this init.R file providing functions](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rpushbullet/blob/master/R/init.R) that are used in [this file in the same package](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rpushbullet/blob/master/R/pushes.R).

Comment: maybe i need to build the package first?

Comment: As I told you two messages ago.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to build the packages and i got error `* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... ERROR
Malformed package name

See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
manual.` can I show you the content of the description file because i feelthe mistake is there

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just typed another question about the description, could you check please? many thanks